Search in CSV and add value if found correct value in another CSV
I have 2 CSV that look like this:
input.csv:



id
sku
costs_production




12
h01



13
h02




search.csv:



sku
costs_production




h01
14.95


h02
51.99



I want to use the value (sku) from search.csv to search for a match in input.csv and, if it finds a match, it should add the corresponding value from cost_production to the cost_production column in input.csv and output it in a new file.
Here's what I've got so far:
    import csv

    ID, SKU, COSTS_PRODUCTION = 'id', 'sku', 'costs_production' # Field names referenced.

    # Read entire input file into a list.
    with open('input.csv', 'r', newline='') as inp:
        reader = csv.DictReader(inp)
        inputs = list(reader)

    # Update input rows that match data in search.csv file.
    with open('search.csv', 'r', newline='') as sea:
        sea_reader = csv.DictReader(sea)
        for row in sea_reader:
            SKU, COSTS_PRODUCTION = row[SKU], row[COSTS_PRODUCTION]
            for input_ in inputs:
                if input_[SKU] == SKU: # Match?
                    input_[COSTS_PRODUCTION] = row[COSTS_PRODUCTION]
                    break

    # Write updated input.csv data out into a file.
    with open('input_updated.csv', 'w', newline='') as outp:
        fieldnames = inputs[0].keys()
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outp, fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(inputs)

    print('done')

I keep getting KeyError: 'h01'.

Please consider fixing your indents.  Also include the full traceback error.

Note the table formatting is less useful than an actual CSV file people can copy-paste. Or, assuming the problem is less in writing to and reading from files than it is processing the data in-between, cut the files out entirely and show a list of dictionaries - give a [mre].

It would be easier if you consider using dataframe in pandas.
For example:
import pandas as pd

input_df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
search_df = pd.read_csv('search.csv')

merged_df = pd.merge(input_df, search_df, on='sku', how='left')

# Fill the costs_production column with the corresponding values from search.csv
merged_df['costs_production'] = merged_df['costs_production_y'].fillna(merged_df['costs_production_x'])

merged_df = merged_df[['id', 'sku', 'costs_production']]
merged_df.to_csv('input_updated.csv', index=False)


However, If you still consider using csv, the issue occurs because the variables holding the column keys (SKU and COSTS_PRODUCTION) and the variables holding the actual values from the CSV rows share the same names. Specifically, the following line causes the problem:
SKU, COSTS_PRODUCTION = row[SKU], row[COSTS_PRODUCTION]

To resolve this, assign the CSV values to uniquely named variables, like so:
# Update input rows that match data in search.csv file.
with open('search.csv', 'r', newline='') as sea:
    sea_reader = csv.DictReader(sea)
    for row in sea_reader:
        search_sku = row[SKU]
        search_costs_production = row[COSTS_PRODUCTION]
        for input_ in inputs:
            if input_[SKU] == search_sku:
                input_[COSTS_PRODUCTION] = search_costs_production
                break


With the help of JayPeerachai, I played around a bit, filtered the results again and then got this as the final solution.
Maybe it will help some of you.
# Update input rows that match data in search.csv file. 
with open('search.csv', 'r', newline='') as sea: 
    sea_reader = csv.DictReader(sea) 
    for row in sea_reader: 
        # SKU, COSTS_PRODUCTION = row[SKU], row[COSTS_PRODUCTION] 
        # SKU = row[SKU] 
        for input_ in inputs: 
            # if input_[SKU] == SKU: # Match? 
            if input_['sku'] == row[SKU]: 
                try: 
                    input_[COSTS_PRODUCTION] = row[COSTS_PRODUCTION] 
                except KeyError: 
                    import ipdb ; ipdb.set_trace() 
                break 


filtered_inputs = [entry for entry in inputs if entry[COSTS_PRODUCTION] != ''] 


fyi: duckdb may be worth looking at
import os
import tempfile
import duckdb

tmpDB=tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile().name

con = duckdb.connect(tmpDB)
con.sql("create table input as select * from read_csv( 'input.csv')")
con.sql("create table search as select * from read_csv( 'search.csv')")
con.sql("COPY (select input.id, input.sku, search.costs_production from input,search where input.sku = search.sku) TO 'input-updated.csv' (HEADER,DELIMITER '\t') ")

os.unlink(tmpDB)

#produces 
id  sku costs_production
12  h01 14.95
13  h02 51.99

